# Dimensions for windows 8 mobile phone splash screen

Tags: windows-phone-8

I read about creating splash screen for windows 8 mobile phone

WXGA

768 × 1,280

SplashScreenImage.screen-WXGA.jpg

My question is simple. Is the dimension Width  by Hieght or the other way round.
I want to know if Width =  768 px
and Height is = 1280 px 
Or it is the other way round.

Please I have check online but they dont really specify. I am new to windows 8 mobile app development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is width x height. Height is the larger number.